# Fate of acoustic phonons in incommensurate charge density wave states?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, acoustics, symmetry-breaking, phonons

In most standard exposition of (the mean-field theory of) charge density wave (CDW), phase and amplitude fluctuations are introduced as the collective excitations. Kohn anomaly in the acoustic phonon dispersion ($\omega^\mathrm{phn}_{Q}\rightarrow0$) is also mentioned as temperature goes from the above till the transition temperature $T_\mathrm{CDW}$, at which phonons condense at momentum $Q=2k_F$.

But where are the acoustic phonons deep in, say, an incommensurate CDW phase? Which of the following is the correct?

- there are still gapless acoustic phonons in the CDW phase, in addition to the phasons
- gapped out and no longer acoustic
- just the same thing as phasons
- merge into phasons

Intuitively, I tend to think phason $\phi$ in $\cos(Q\cdot x+\phi)$ as a generalized acoutic phonon since phonon seems to be just setting $Q=0$ as a special case for normal solids.